# Where is Channel.setInterestOps in Netty 4x

Tags: java, netty

I am using netty for developing my server.
I am looking for setting the setInterestOps for a channel.
In netty 3 there is a method call setInterestOps  in Channel class.
But in netty 4 I can't find it.
Can anybody tell me where it is?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Channel.setInterestOps()` in Netty 3 was used to suspend or resume the read operation of a Netty `Channel`.  Its name and mechanic were unnecessarily low-level, so we changed how we deal with the suspension and resumption of the inbound traffic.

First, we added a new outbound operation called `read()`.  When `read()` is invoked, Netty will read inbound traffic once, and it will trigger at least one `channelRead()` event and a single `channelReadComplete()` event.  Usually, you continue to read by calling `ctx.read()` in `channelReadComplete()`.

However, because having to call `ctx.read()` for every `channelReadComplete()` is not very interesting, Netty has an option called `autoRead`, which is turned on by default.  When `autoRead` is on, Netty will automatically trigger a `read()` operation on every `channelReadComplete()`.

Therefore, If you want to suspend the inbound traffic, all you need to do is to turn the `autoRead` option off.  To resume, turn it back on.

Answer (score 1):

Use Channel.config().setAutoRead(true/false);

Comment: Thank you for replying. The documentation for the function says "Sets if ChannelHandlerContext.read() will be invoked automatically so that a user application doesn't need to call it at all. The default value is true." But for Channel.setReadable it is "Suspends or resumes the read operation of the I/O thread asynchronously." The docs for setAutoRead sounds confusing to me. Does both mean the same thing?